# Boost unit test framework: include main function of my codebase

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a codebase on which I want to perform tests. One of the files of this codebase contains code that I want to test, in addition to the main function of the program.

When I add this file to my CMakeLists, it complains about the inclusion of multiple main functions.

Here's how things look:

RunTest.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

MyTest1.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test_1_module
#define BOOST_TEST_DYNAMIC_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp>
#include <boost/test/results_collector.hpp>

#include "../MyCode.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_one)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE {
...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Here's what my CMakeLists look like:

```
SET (
    TestRunner

    RunTest.cpp
    MyCode.cpp #contains a main function
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(TestRunner $TestRunner)
```

How can I solve this? Is there any way to ask boost to ignore the main function in my codebase?

Comment: You have `main` defined in a header file?!

Comment: No, it's in a cpp file.

Comment: Well, anyway... just separate your code properly, such that the *.cpp with `main` in it doesn't contain much anything else.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that this is shared code, so not easy to do. Do you see any other solution?

Comment: If you cannot modify the file with `main` in it, then what will you do anyway if your tests detect an error in it? I think either giving up and not unit-testing this piece of untestable code, or investing your energy in modifying the untestable code to make it testable will both prove more productive than trying to find a hack for the problem.

Comment: Well, I can't modify that file, but I can modify files downstream. However, I need to compile this top file (with main) to be able to run the files downstream as well.

Comment: Hmm, you can compile without a provided `main` by defining [`BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_no_main.html). This gets rid of the the multiple main error. But this does not really solve your problem if you cannot change `main` because you have to register your tests somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I think the only way to go is splitting the main function. Will have to do some PR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the error of multiple `main` functions in the test exe I split up the project into two projects. CMake code:

```
add_library (MyProject_base STATIC ${MYPROJECT_BASE_SRC})
add_executable (MyProject ${MYPROJECT_SRC})
add_executable (MyProject_Test ${MYPROJECT_TEST_SRC})

target_link_libraries(MyProject_base
    #stuff
)
target_link_libraries(MyProject
    MyProject_base
    #stuff
)        
target_link_libraries (MyProject_Test
    MyProject_base
    #stuff
)
```

Now `MyProject_base` is build as a static library that is linked to the actual executable `MyProject` as well as to the test exe `MyProject_Test`. Then the code in `MyProject_base` is unit-tested while `MyProject` is nothing more than a main function that of-course is *not* unit-tested.